# Android, proxy and Authentication

Tags: java, android, proxy

As part of the development of an Android application for my business, I have to communicate with a through a proxy with authentication server.

Here's the code I wrote:

```
final HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) new                         URL(url).openConnection(new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new             InetSocketAddress(PROXY_NAME, PROXY_PORT)));

Authenticator.setDefault(new NtlmAuthenticator(PROXY_USERNAME, PROXY_PASSWORD));

connection.setConnectTimeout(5000);
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8");
connection.setDoInput(true);
connection.setDoOutput(true);

final int retCode = connection.getResponseCode();

System.out.println("Return code : " + retCode);
```

with the class

```
private class NtlmAuthenticator extends Authenticator {
    private final String username;
    private final String password;

    public NtlmAuthenticator(final String username, final String password) {
        super();
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
    }

    @Override
    public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
        System.out.println("Get password auth");
        return (new PasswordAuthentication(username, password.toCharArray()));
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, I still get a response code equal to 407 and I've realized that I never spent in the method getPasswordAuthentication

The same program works very well with a Java program not Android.

My version of Android is 4.4.4 and I have seen it used OkHttp for queries. By debugging and entering the code of Android, I've realized that the object contained OkHttp well my proxy configuration but not my authenticator.

Could you help me ?

Thank you

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?  I am facing a similar question